# Php mysql min and max price range

Tags: php, mysql, max, min

Hi I am wanting to create a page that enables the user to select a min and max price from a drop down menu and be display results from a database in that price range. I have my database set up just not sure where to go next. Ive done research and found this code:

```
$min = (int)$_GET['min'];
$max = (int)$_GET['max'];

$sql = "Select * from golf_courses where price>=$min and price<=$max";
```

Is this right to use and how do you set up the select box to link to this php code and the database prices?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Seems right, why not give it a go? Best way to know...

I would concatenate the variables with the string though like `" . $min . "`

Comment: Please add your HTML code, too.

Comment: Apologies but I dont even know what that means, new to php. :/

Comment: enenen, I havent done the html part yet. Thats what I was asking, how do I set that up so that it links? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `min` and `max` values will need to be the `name` attributes of your `select` elements, like such:

```
<select name="min">
  <option value="0">None</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  ...
</select>
```

If you're using a `form` in the traditional sense (i.e. posting values to a PHP page) then the variables will actually live in `$_POST`, and you will need to access them there instead of `$_GET`. If you use the `method="GET"` attribute/value on your `form` tag then you can make the request with a GET instead. The basic difference here is whether you want the values to show up in the query string or not. For instance, using `method="POST"` will take you to `example.php`, whereas using `method="GET"` will send you to `example.php?min=2&max=3`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry im new to php so im not really sure what that means. Lol. Put in the select form with code above. Doesnt do anything though.

Comment: I suggest you read up on forms (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form) and then how to process them in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) - you'll quickly get the hang of it! :)